# How can I determine when a new "place" is added to the Google Places database?

Tags: google-places-api

How can I determine when a new "place" is added to the Google Places database?  Is there some sort of method I can use to query the Google Places API by date added?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no method to do this. If you believe this would be a useful feature, please file a [Places API Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).